# How can I add two 'add to cart' ubercart buttons in a product page

Tags: ubercart

I would like to have two 'add to cart' buttons on my ubercart drupal site. 
I've set up two views, but only one button will show at a time. 
Why is this? 
You can see it on https://www.thepetwiki.com/mg-testsite.com/ubercart/painting/please
There should be an 'add to cart' button next to both 'BUY: $2,400'

Answer (score 0):

I would recommend creating a view:block that displays the product's price and an add to cart button, you can then duplicate the view:block and have in the block admin page, add the two new view blocks to the regions you would like them displayed in.

Comment: If you look at my site https://www.thepetwiki.com/mg-testsite.com/ubercart/painting/please you will and view source you will see I have the view:block showing twice and two 'add to cart' buttons, however on the display you only see one. Why won't the other button show? I've tried everything! In IE it never shows in other browsers it sometimes shows. What is going on? Thanks